# BeautifulSoup loop fails to capture content

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

My BeautifulSoup scraper loops through a list of URLs and captures one of my criteria ('month_year') as desired. But each 'li' tag in the second loop merely extracts details for the first instance on the page.

The 'month_year' doesn't change for a given URL, and that's fine. But 'broadcast' should return different details for each 'li' tag.

Any advice for a novice?

```
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen


contents = []
with open('monthly_list.csv','r') as csvf:
    urls = csv.reader(csvf)
    for url in urls:
        page = urlopen(url[0]).read()
        tunes = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
        playlist = tunes.find('ul', class_='content-container row')
        daily_URLs_data = open('daily_URLs_2007-2018.csv', 'a')
        for li in playlist.find_all('div', class_='description'):
            month_year = tunes.find('div', class_='resultsHeader').text
            broadcast = playlist.h3.a
            print (month_year)
            print (broadcast)
            csv_writer.writerow([month_year, broadcast])
```

Comment: ... you are not using `li` inside that loop. You could move `month_year =` and `broadcast =` lines outside the loop and obtain the same result.

Comment: I thought having those lines inside the loop was sufficient, but now I see that was incorrect. Thanks, @Bakuriu, for helping me out!